# How do I get coordinate outline/shape of a street give a single coordinate

Tags: python, location, maps

I am trying to create a function using python that takes in a single coordinate on a street and returns coordinates outlining the street, 250 meters in each direction of the street. Not sure where to start.

Say my input is: 43.647839, -79.489579

The function should return:
43.647813, -79.487963
43.64785183872775, -79.48887121891023
43.64791782707461, -79.48967051719667
43.64802651360553, -79.49031961177828
43.64825941265234, -79.49100625728609
43.648037, -79.491121
43.647723743494616, -79.4900728485489
43.64761505641589, -79.48883366798403
43.64761505641589, -79.4879646322632
43.647813, -79.487963

https://www.mapcustomizer.com/map/street%20outline

[[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ybLp4.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eyT6n.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/If36G.png)